# How to call a webassembly method in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, c, vue.js, emscripten, webassembly

I'm trying to transpose to vue.js this simple html page add.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="callAdd()" />

    <script>
      function callAdd() {
        const result = Module.ccall('Add',
            'number',
            ['number', 'number'],
            [1, 2]);

        console.log(`Result: ${result}`);
      }
    </script>
    <script src="js_plumbing.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

which calls the Add function defined in add.c   :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <emscripten.h>

// If this is an Emscripten (WebAssembly) build then...
#ifdef __EMSCRIPTEN__
  #include <emscripten.h>
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" { // So that the C++ compiler does not rename our function names
#endif

EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE
int Add(int value1, int value2) 
{
  return (value1 + value2); 
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

and converted to js_plumbing and js_plumbling.wasm files through the command:

```
emcc add.c -o js_plumbing.js -s EXTRA_EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS=['ccall','cwrap'] -s 
ENVIRONMENT='web','worker'
```

In console of google chrome I get these errors:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/dist/js_plumbing.wasm 404 (Not Found)  @  js_plumbing.js?2b2c:1653
```

Where in js_plumbing_js :

```
// Prefer streaming instantiation if available.
  function instantiateAsync() {
    if (!wasmBinary &&
        typeof WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming === 'function' &&
        !isDataURI(wasmBinaryFile) &&
        typeof fetch === 'function') {
      fetch(wasmBinaryFile, { credentials: 'same-origin' }).then(function (response) {  // <---------------!!!
        var result = WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(response, info);
        return result.then(receiveInstantiatedSource, function(reason) {
            // We expect the most common failure cause to be a bad MIME type for the binary,
            // in which case falling back to ArrayBuffer instantiation should work.
            err('wasm streaming compile failed: ' + reason);
            err('falling back to ArrayBuffer instantiation');
            instantiateArrayBuffer(receiveInstantiatedSource);
          });
      });
    } else {
      return instantiateArrayBuffer(receiveInstantiatedSource);
    }
  }
```

In Google Chrome: createWasm             @  js_plumbing.js?2b2c:1680

line 1680 of js_plumbing.js:

```
instantiateAsync();
```

in Google Chrome: eval                          @   js_plumbing.js?2b2c:1930

line 1930 of js_plumbing.js:

```
<pre><font color="#4E9A06">var</font> asm = createWasm();</pre>
```

And many other errors related to wasm :

[image]

[image]

So... how should I modify the callAdd() method in Result.vue in order to correctly execute the Add function in js_plumbing.js and in js_plumbing.wasm files?

```
  methods: {
    callAdd() {
      const result = Module.ccall('Add',
          'number',
          ['number', 'number'],
          [1, 2]);
      console.log('Result: ${result}');
    }
  }
```

Updates:

1 update)

I compiled the add.c with this command:

```
emcc add.c -o js_plumbing.mjs -s EXTRA_EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS=
['ccall','cwrap'] -s ENVIRONMENT='web' .
```

Then created a js_plumbing.js  file :

```
. import wasm from './js_plumbing.mjs';

const instance = wasm({
  onRuntimeInitialized() {
    console.log(instance._addTwoNumbers(3,2));
  }
}) .
```

Doing npm run dev:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/components/js_plumbing.mjs 3:25
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (3:25)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently 
no loaders are configured to process this file. 
See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| 
| var Module = (function() {
>   var _scriptDir = import.meta.url;
|   
|   return (
```

Update 2)

I solved the 404 error by putting the wasm file into a /div subfolder within the same folder of the index.html file.

Now I’m facing this problem: “Cannot read property ‘ccall’ of undefined”
[image]

But I compiled the add.c file, creating js_plumbing.js and js_plumbing.wasm files, with this command, which exports the methods ‘ccall’ and ‘cwrap’ :

emcc add.c -o js_plumbing.js -s EXTRA_EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS=[‘ccall’,‘cwrap’] -s ENVIRONMENT=‘web’,‘worker’

3° Update)

I "solved" through  a sort of an hack, which I do not like at all.

This is the Result.vue file:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p button @click="callAdd">Add!</p>
    <p>Result: {{ result }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    import * as js_plumbing from './js_plumbing'
    import Module  from './js_plumbing'
    export default {
      data () {
        return {
          result: null
        }
      },
      methods: {
        callAdd () {
          const result = js_plumbing.Module.ccall('Add',
            'number',
            ['number', 'number'],
            [1, 2]);
          this.result = result;
        }
      }
    }
</script>
```

which is exactly the same as the one used before

The only thing I've done to make it working, is to add export to the definition of Module in js_plumbing.js :

js_plumbing.js

```
// Copyright 2010 The Emscripten Authors.  All rights reserved.
// Emscripten is available under two separate licenses, the MIT 
license and the
// University of Illinois/NCSA Open Source License.  Both these 
licenses can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

// The Module object: Our interface to the outside world. We import
// and export values on it. There are various ways Module can be used:
// 1. Not defined. We create it here
// 2. A function parameter, function(Module) { ..generated code.. }
// 3. pre-run appended it, var Module = {}; ..generated code..
// 4. External script tag defines var Module.
// We need to check if Module already exists (e.g. case 3 above).
// Substitution will be replaced with actual code on later stage of 
the build,
// this way Closure Compiler will not mangle it (e.g. case 4. above).
// Note that if you want to run closure, and also to use Module
// after the generated code, you will need to define   var Module = 
{};
// before the code. Then that object will be used in the code, and you
// can continue to use Module afterwards as well.
export var Module = typeof Module !== 'undefined' ? Module : {};
```

[image]

But, as I said, I do not like this hack.
Any suggestions on how to make the Module exportable, thus importable, without manually adding 'export' in js_plumbing.js file?

Comment: Which JS module syntax are you using in Vue? `require()` or `import X from Y`?

Comment: @AnthumChris in /components/Result.vue : import * as js_plumbing from './js_plumbing'

Comment: Looks like this thread is duplicated at https://forum.vuejs.org/t/wasm-how-to-correctly-call-a-webassembly-method-in-vue-js/83422

Answer (score 3):

First, the 404 error should be addressed.  Does file `/dist/js_plumbing.wasm` exist?  I've needed to copy .wasm files manually in the past because some automatic build systems (like Parcel) currently don't.

You can build with the `MODULARIZE` option to import into your build system.

**addTwoNumbers.c**

```
#include <emscripten.h>

EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE
int addTwoNumbers(int value1, int value2) 
{
  return (value1 + value2); 
}
```

**build command**

```
$ emcc -o dist/addTwoNumbers.js -s MODULARIZE=1 src/addTwoNumbers.c
```

**Vue Implementation**

```
import myMathModule from './js_plumbing';

let instance = {
  ready: new Promise(resolve => {
    myMathModule({
      onRuntimeInitialized() {
        instance = Object.assign(this, {
          ready: Promise.resolve()
        });
        resolve();
      }
    });
  })
};

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      result: null
    };
  },
  methods: {
    callAdd(a, b) {
      instance.ready
      .then(_ => this.result = instance._add(a, b));
    }
  }
};
```

Use the `onRuntimeInitialized` method to detect when the WASM module is ready.  Your exported functions will have an underscore in front of them.

`require()` could possibly be used in place of `import`:

```
const wasmModule = require('./addTwoNumbers.js');

...
```

Comment: I updated my question with the result of my attempt to follow your hints

Comment: I updated my question (update 2) : solved the 404 error message but now I'm facing this problem:  “Cannot read property ‘ccall’ of undefined”

Comment: How did you call the wasm Add function in Result.vue?